# how to position footer with contents that has float properties

Tags: html, css, footer, positioning

one of our project is to create this basic website that has a homepage, Login-page, admin-page.

I have made the basic outline, I just cant properly fix the positionings of the divs.
All pages must have a header and footer and should be consistent to all pages.

On my admin-page,
I have the header properly positioned. the content is 6 pictures in 3x2 grid which I have done using float lefs to arrange them. but my footer cant position itself at the verybottom of the page even tho it has the `bottom: 0px;` I cant seem to make it work.

how do I fix this?

PS. This is my first time asking in this website, I dont know how to show my code so you all can see what I did.

```css
.foot {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-image: url(images/maoheader.jpg);
  background-size: contain;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.sepfoot {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-image: url(images/divider.png);
  background-size: contain;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 74px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.foot1 {
  padding: 15px;
}

.stud {
  width: 550px;
  height: 350px;
  border: rgb(70, 24, 49) solid 3px;
}

.sFrame {
  width: 550px;
  height: 350px;
  margin: 40px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<!-- this is div dor header-->
<div>
  <div class="header">
    <!-- <button type"button" style="position:absolute; right:20px; 
    top:10px;" class="but"><a href="Index.html">Home Page</a></button> -->
    <h1 class="stroke">KIA ORA AOTEAROA</h1>
    <p class="phead">LIBRARY NAME</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="sep"></div>

<!-- this is div for page content -->
<div class="test">

  <div class="nav">A-Z</div>
  <div class="nav">FICTION</div>
  <div class="nav">NON-FICTION</div>
  <div class="nav">AUTHOR</div>

  <div>
    <div class="sFrame"><img src="images/s1.jpg" class="stud"></div>
    <div class="sFrame"><img src="images/s2.jpg" class="stud"></div>
    <div class="sFrame"><img src="images/s3.jpg" class="stud"></div>
    <div class="sFrame"><img src="images/s4.jpg" class="stud"></div>
    <div class="sFrame"><img src="images/s5.jpg" class="stud"></div>
    <div class="sFrame"><img src="images/s6.jpg" class="stud"></div>
  </div>

  <!-- this is footer -->
  <div class="foot">
    <div class="sepfoot"></div>
    <p class="foot1">Created by: Pete Castolome<br> s00019257
      <br> +64 021 23456789<br>
      <email>petecastolome@yahoo.com</email>
    </p>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: You can add code with formatting by selecting your code and formatting it with the `{ }` icon in the editor toolbar. This will indent it in by 4 spaces which will tell the editor is it code to be formatted. You can see the formatted output below.

Comment: You probably got this part already, but you will need the `position` property in tandem with `bottom`. However, you probably do not need to position your elements at all. Instead rely on the "source order", header before content before footer, and the elements will sit one below the other and will have an intrinsic height based on the elements in each section.

Comment: @dylanjameswagner I have tried applying the "source order" but whats happening is, my footer will initialy positioned at the bottom of the screen even tho there are still page contents that needs to be scrolled. and if I scroll it down, it looks like the footer is in the middle of the website..

Comment: Your `.foot` is inside `.test` and test is only as tall as its content, so when you position the footer it's being positioned at the bottom of `.test`, or its overlaying your other content. I can't tell without putting it all together on my machine.

Comment: The overlap should not happen if you do not position any elements. Intrinsically, a footer would exist at the "bottom" of the document which might not be the bottom of the viewport if the page content is short.

Comment: There is a thing sometimes called a "sticky footer" that will always be at the bottom regardless of the height of the content, but it is a more advanced technique that can be difficult to get right and work when the content is short AND when it is longer than the viewport.

Comment: I have moved it out of the test div. results still the same.
I did remove the ```position``` on my .foot and .sepfoot. What it did, it positioned itself just below my header.

Comment: Your `.test` page content, is all `float`ed — `.sFrame`. This affectively makes the height of the content `0`, and have no "layout".

Comment: I would suggest you use `position` sparingly and only when you need to overlap things, and only use `float` when you want text to "wrap" around an image in content. Explore `display: flex;` for layout like columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comments above...

I would suggest you use position sparingly and only when you need to overlap things, and only use float when you want text to "wrap" around an image in content. Explore `display: flex;` for layout like columns.

Example:

Remove all your `position`ing, stick with source order for now. As the page content gets longer the footer will exist at the bottom of the content.

For the page content:

HTML

```
<div class="flex-parent">
     <div class="flex-child sFrame"><img src="images/s1.jpg" class="stud"></div>
     <div class="flex-child sFrame"><img src="images/s2.jpg" class="stud"></div>
     <div class="flex-child sFrame"><img src="images/s3.jpg" class="stud"></div>
     <div class="flex-child sFrame"><img src="images/s4.jpg" class="stud"></div>
     <div class="flex-child sFrame"><img src="images/s5.jpg" class="stud"></div>
     <div class="flex-child sFrame"><img src="images/s6.jpg" class="stud"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.flex-parent {
    diplay: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-child {
    width: calc(100% / 3);
}
```

Comment: If you really want/need a "sticky footer" you can use `flex` or `grid` on `body` along with other supporting styes, but as mentioned in above comments it can be a bit fiddly to get right.

Comment: thanks man! the flex property fixed my content positions and mainting my footer at the bottom of everything. exactly what I wanted to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Just get your footer DIV out of any containers and it will work. Also please note that, if in case your page content has less height to fill up the window display height, the footer may appear above the bottom line. A "min-height: 100%;" to BODY tag will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.foot{
width: 100%;
height: 150px;   
background-image: url(images/maoheader.jpg);
background-size: contain;
display:flex;
bottom: 0;
}

.sepfoot{
height: 150px;
background-image: url(images/divider.png);
background-size: contain;
position: relative;
/*bottom: 74px;*/
z-index: 1;
}

.foot1{
padding: 15px;
}
.stud{
width: 550px;
height: 350px;
border: rgb(70, 24, 49) solid 3px;

}

.sFrame{
width: 550px;
height: 350px;
margin: 40px;
position: relative;
float: left;
}

#exampleimg { width:150px;
              height:150px;
              background:black;}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Admin Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body class="container">
<!-- this is div dor header-->
<div>   
<div class="header">
    
   <!-- <button type"button" style="position:absolute; right:20px; 
top:10px;" class="but"><a href="Index.html">Home Page</a></button> -->
        <h1 class="stroke">KIA ORA AOTEAROA</h1>
        <p class="phead">LIBRARY NAME</p>  
</div>

</div>
   <div class="sep"></div>

<!-- this is div for page content -->
<div class="test">

        <div class="nav">A-Z</div>
        <div class="nav">FICTION</div>
        <div class="nav">NON-FICTION</div>
        <div class="nav">AUTHOR</div>

    <div>
     <div class="sFrame"><img src="images/s1.jpg" class="stud"></div>
     <div class="sFrame"><img src="images/s2.jpg" class="stud"></div>
     <div class="sFrame"><img src="images/s3.jpg" class="stud"></div>
     <div class="sFrame"><img src="images/s4.jpg" class="stud"></div>
     <div class="sFrame"><img src="images/s5.jpg" class="stud"></div>
     <div class="sFrame"><img src="images/s6.jpg" class="stud"></div>

    </div>

<!-- this is footer -->

    <div class="foot">
        <div class="sepfoot"> 
             <div id="exampleimg"></div>
        </div>
      <p class="foot1">Created by: Pete Castolome<br>
              s00019257<br>
              +64 021 23456789<br>
              <email>petecastolome@yahoo.com</email></p>
        </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

i add display:flex and remove the position:absolute in .foot
is this what you want??

--

you mean like this?

Comment: It did the job. now I need my .sepfoot to be repositioned. what I am aiming with the sepfoot is just design. I am overlaping the picture to my footer so it looks like a border. on my other pages, my code looks right, but on my admin-page it is between my .nav and .test container where the pictures are..

Comment: if it is not, can you add any img about that footer that you want?

Comment: I got what I wanted to happen, thanks for the display flex idea.